# codeblocks autocomplete / calltips not working for C standard library functions

Tags: c, codeblocks, standard-library

I'm trying to start using code::blocks to do some C programming in just to learn. I was hoping to use the codecompletion / calltips feature (e.g. when typing say "printf" it popsup a handy dropdown box that shows the parameters.

I've made a new project and a new file in that project called "hello.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int test=0;
  printf("%d",test);
  return 0;
}
```

but midway through typing prin---only "priority_queue and private" show up, no printf functions, and nothing happens when pressing ctrl-j, ctrl-space, alt-shift-space, ctrl-n or p nothing works. I've tried reparsing the project. I initially had 13.12 version installed because that's what Ubuntu (14.04.4LTS) had but then I installed version 16.01 by mucking with the apt-get ppas. That version also doesn't work. I've tried disabling and reenabling the code completion plugin and I've made sure under settings->editor-> that code completion box is checked.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your IDE settings are really wrong (or Code::Blocks is a bad IDE), since `private` and `priority_queue` are not even C-related, but C++ words.

Comment: Right exactly. I made sure I selected "C" when creating the new file in the project and not even "C++". But even if I had selected C++, the inclusion of the <stdio.h> header file in a C++ context should still read the header and make an appropriate popup, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The new Code::Blocks IDE is not so polished on Ubuntu yet. You can try reinstalling it. And if it didn't work try reverting to 13.12.

Comment: Hrm. Thanks for the headsup. I initially did have 13.12 (The default install from the usual apt-get repo) and it didn't work there either...very frustrating. Seems like a neat IDE. I may try eclipse though I hear eclipse CDT calltips and popups are also wonky.