# code blocks autocomplete for C functions not working

Tags: c, autocomplete, codeblocks

like explained  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444091/codeblocks-autocomplete-calltips-not-working-for-c-standard-library-functions)

I am using code blocks 13.12 mingw TDM-GCC and when I for example write `#include <stdio.h>` and then try to type printf, no suggestions would appear! What should I do?

more explanation:

I use .cpp for writing c but it doesn't make any difference when i use .c

codecompletion works fine for C++ functions like cout and cin.

It doesn't work for header files both for C and C++ (like stdio.h and iostream)

after including stdio.h, when i type 'prin' there is no suggestion for printf

It works fine for keywords like int or char

autocomplete in 17.12 doesn't work, too. (I think this is not about code blocks version due to my next clue)

In my university computers, they use the exact same code blocks but autocomplete completely works! so i wonder what i should have done! (both windows 10)

for me, code blocks is installed in D:\Programs\CodeBlocks

Comment: Check in  `/Settings/Editor/General Settings/` if `Code Completion` is Checked.

Comment: Yes the setting is ok https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/9/2e6d06e1f74ca1a7522a875553c3779a-full.png